# ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent (Oracle linux connection to Sql Server Windows)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc

i have 2 server.

1 server is SQl Server 2014 on windows

- Hostname : 192.168.0.190
- Username : demo
- Password: demo
- port: 1433

1 Server is Oracle Linux 12c

The problem : When i try to do a sql request on my sql Server from Oracle linux, i got this error :

```
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from SQLSERVER1
```

This is my initdg4odbc.ora :

```
# This is a sample agent init file that contains the HS parameters that are
# needed for the Database Gateway for ODBC

#
# HS init parameters
#
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = SQLSERVER1
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = DEBUG
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /usr/lib64/libodbc.so
#HS_LANGUAGE = American_America.we8iso8859p1
#HS_KEEP_REMOTE_COLUMN_SIZE = LOCAL
#HS_FDS_RECOVERY_ACCOUNT = RECOVER
#HS_FDS_RECOVERY_PWD = RECOVER


#
# ODBC specific environment variables
#

set ODBCINI= /etc/odbc.ini

#
# Environment variables required for the non-Oracle system
#
#set <envvar>=<value>
```

> This is my tnsnames.ora:

```
LISTENER_ORALIN =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = test.ehk.ht)(PORT = 1521))

SQLSERVER1 =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=test.ehk.ht)(PORT=1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SQLSERVER1))
      (HS=OK)
    )
```

This is my listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = test.ehk.ht)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

# From Oracle 11gR1 onwards use this.
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
   (SID_DESC=
     (SID_NAME=SQLSERVER1)
     (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1)
     (ENVS="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/lib")
     (PROGRAM=dg4odbc)
   )
 )
```

> I choose the port 1433 because it's my dynamic port

I tried too 1522, nothing has change. I have always
the same message.

My username and password are "test" and "testpassword"

This is my file odbc.ini :

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
MSSQLSERVER= MSSQL Server

[GESFILM]
# Reference driver from the "/etc/odbcinst.ini" file.
# Driver = FreeTDS
# Or use a direct driver reference, rather than reference
# one in the "/etc/odbcinst.ini" file.
Driver = SQLSERVER1
Description = MSSQL Server
Trace = yes
TraceFile = /usr/local/bin/sqlncli-11.0.1790.0/lib64
Server = 192.168.0.190
Database = test
UserName = test
Password = testpassword
Port = 1433
TDS_Version = 7.2
#QuotedId = YES
#AnsiNPW = YES
#VarMaxAsLong = YES

[Default]
Driver = SQLSERVER1
```

> When i try to connect with "isql", that work

[image]

This is how i think i have to create my databseLink:

> CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK SQLSERVER1 CONNECT TO "demo" IDENTIFIED BY "demo" USING 'SQLSERVER1';

After a request sql, i got this error :

```
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from SQLSERVER1
```

I tried 3 others way to create my databaselink:

1 :

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK "demo" CONNECT TO "test" IDENTIFIED BY testpasword USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.190)(PORT=1433))(CONNECT_DATA= (SID=SQLSERVER1)))';
```

2:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK "demo" CONNECT TO "test" IDENTIFIED BY testpasword USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.190)(PORT=1522))(CONNECT_DATA= (SID=SQLSERVER1)))';
```

3:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK "demo" CONNECT TO "test" IDENTIFIED BY testpasword USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.190)(PORT=3389))(CONNECT_DATA= (SID=SQLSERVER1)))';
```

I got a different error for each databaselink.(Execution in the same order than creation of each databse link)

1:
 ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed

2:
 - ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

3:
- ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

What is wrong? How can i resolve my error to be able to do a request sql on my SQlServer from Oracle ?

Thank you!

Comment: Images of text are very poorly received, please paste the actualy text into your question please.

Comment: No problem, i will do it the next time i work. It's in 2 days . But if you could try to help it could be nice .

Comment: Why do it next time? Users are far less likely to provide aid if they need to transcribe your images.

Comment: Is the instance name `GESFIM` or `GESFILM`? You use both in your question.

Comment: GESFIM, it's fix

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have your tnsnames.ora entry configured to point directly to the MSSQL server and database (server and port).  This is incorrect.  It should point to the listener.  Listener is configured on server 'agencesprov.edh.ht' on port 1521.  So that is what your tnsnames.ora should point to.

As a separate issue, 'unable to retreive text of message' is actually a secondary error.  It usually means that the ORACLE_HOME was not set properly, and as a result, the failing module was unable to find the text of the error message, located in a file under ORACLE_HOME.  All it can then do is report the error code of the primary error, which in this case is 65535.  You can see more about how to connect all the pieces of a gateway connection from oracle to mssql, at https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/the-oracle-transparent-gateway/

Comment: It's done and now i got this error : This is my new error :

ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message: ORA-02063: preceding line from SQLSERVER1

Answer (score 0):

I have change my file tnsames.ora :

```
ORALIN =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = agencesprov.edh.ht)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oralin.edh.ht)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORALIN =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = agencesprov.edh.ht)(PORT = 1521))


SQLSERVER1 =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=agencesprov.edh.ht)(PORT=1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SQLSERVER1))
      (HS=OK)
    )

LISTENER_SQLSERVER1 =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=agencesprov.edh.ht)(PORT=1521))
```

It is suppose to be like that?

This is my new error :

> ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this
>   message: ORA-02063: preceding line from SQLSERVER1

Thank you!

Comment: "preceding line from SQLSERVER1".  So you know that your request made it _to_ the mssql database, thus proving that most, if not all of the network config (db link definition, tnsnames, listener, otg files, odbc config) is correct.  Were there any other messages besides the two shown?  Can you test the connection from the odbc driver, thus bypassing and eliminating  the oracle database and oracle gateway components from the problem?

Comment: I had not the file initSQLSERVER1.init. Now i have the file so this part work. But, a last past don't work., i will do another answer to be able to read.

Answer (score 0):

I had not the file SQLSERVER1.ini, that's why i had these errors. Now, i got a new error.

I try the connection without oracle :

```
isql -v GESFIM test testpassword
```

That work.

Now, i try to do the same thing with oracle :

```
select count(*) from test123@SQLSERVER1;
```

[image]

this is my initSQLSERVER1.ora :

```
    # This is a sample agent init file that contains the HS parameters that are
# needed for the Database Gateway for ODBC

#
# HS init parameters
#
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = SQLSERVER1
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = DEBUG
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /usr/lib64/libodbc.so
HS_LANGUAGE=American_America.we8iso8859p1
HS_KEEP_REMOTE_COLUMN_SIZE = LOCAL
HS_FDS_RECOVERY_ACCOUNT=RECOVER
HS_FDS_RECOVERY_PWD=RECOVER


#
# ODBC specific environment variables
#

set ODBCINI= /etc/odbc.ini
#
# Environment variables required for the non-Oracle system
#
#set <envvar>=<value>
```

this is my odbc.ini :

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
MSSQLSERVER= MSSQL Server

[GESFIM]
# Reference driver from the "/etc/odbcinst.ini" file.
# Driver          = FreeTDS
# Or use a direct driver reference, rather than reference
# one in the "/etc/odbcinst.ini" file.
Driver          = /usr/local/bin/sqlncli-11.0.1790.0/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0
Description     = MSSQL Server
Trace           = yes
TraceFile       = /usr/local/bin/sqlncli-11.0.1790.0/lib64
Server      = 192.168.0.190
Database        = test
UserName    = test
Password    = testpassword
Port            = 1433
TDS_Version     = 7.2
#QuotedId=YES
#AnsiNPW=YES
#VarMaxAsLong=YES

[Default]
Driver          = /usr/local/bin/sqlncli-11.0.1790.0/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0
```

Why no data source name and no driver found? That work manually. I think he don't find odbc.ini or something like that.

What is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: According to your initSQLSERVER1.ora, your odbc dsn is 'SQLSERVER1'  (HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = SQLSERVER1).  But then in your odbc.ini, I don't see any entry for SQLSERVER1.

Comment: in odbc.ini, where i am suppose to put SQLSERVER1 ? It is suppose to replace GESFIM?